# Can I remove accumulated sawdust from fiberglass insulation?

Tags: insulation, basement-insulation

I have an unfinished basement with framed and insulated (the yellow fiberglass stuff) walls, but no sheet rock. Over time there has been a lot of accumulation of sawdust on the insulation as the area is a workshop. I'm now planning to finish the room. I want to remove the sawdust but I don't see a practical way to vacuum the dust without continually sucking in insulation. Is there a practical way to do this or should I replace the insulation?[image: Insulation with sawdust]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a vacuum cleaner with a upholstery brush attachment, or "round brush". Hold the insulation with one hand and vacuum with the other.

If you still have problems with loose insulation, lower the suction either with an adjustable vacuum or with a bypass-hole.

Minor amounts of sawdust can be left in the insulation. It's not uncommon for dust to accumulate during electrical/plumbing installations and for it to remain there during insulation and close-up.

Comment: yes do that, also wear gloves and a dust mask.

Answer (score 3):

Blow it out with compressed air instead.  Any of the modern, "made safer" type blow guns should be weak enough to not tear up the insulation.  (I'm thinking air off a compressor, not "canned air" (basically freon), the latter wouldn't be powerful enough.

Then, in the future, don't do woodwork around unfaced insulation.  I totally sympathize with not wanting to drywall, because access to utilities is a huge money saver. But at the least, staple up some 4-mil plastic sheeting and replace it every few years when it gets rotten.